# How to convert a WebService Response to a PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

**INTRODUCTION**

I'm trying to integrate Europass Webservice with the website that I'm currently developing.

This WebService allows you to, through a XML or JSON file, obtain either a PDF or a Word CV.

They Provide the information to communicate with their WS and a Sample XML [(here)](http://interop.europass.cedefop.europa.eu/web-services/remote-upload/), but you can do your own, since you respect their schema.

To ensure that the xml is okay use the remote upload service and see the resulting CV from your XML in their website.

I'm using the REST Service, more specifically XML to PDF CV

**MY DOUBT**

My problem is that I can comunicate with the Web service and I also Get a OK Response (Great!), However when downloading the PDF it is all blank.

What am I Missing here?Can you guys please guide me?

To reproduce this, copy the code below and add the content of this [xml](http://goo.gl/XyM7Ma) to the file in the xmlcontent path.

**CODE**

```
        //POST
        string xmlContent = File.ReadAllText("D:\\Documents\\CV.xml");
        string URL = "https://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/rest/v1/document/to/pdf-cv";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        using (Stream webStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            requestWriter.Write(xmlContent);
        }

        //RESPONSE
        try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (webStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                    {
                        string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                        byte[] byteResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (response);
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf"); // Save file         
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteResponse.Length.ToString());
                        Response.Charset = "";
                        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                        Response.BinaryWrite(byteResponse);
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the 'Response' object? Don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: I think what you missed here is this (from the site): "in a parameter called europass-xml. "
You are passing a valid XML, just not in the expected container. That's why they are using a textarea named europass-xml to post the xml directly to their site.

Comment: Hello @JunaidKirkire, The Response Object is associated to the Page object. This object allows you to send HTTP response data to a client and contains information about that response. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.response%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I'm Using ASP.NET 4.5 Framework

Comment: @LocEngineer but if something went wrong how could I receive an OK Response? cheers

Comment: You sent a correct response. But when they query for the container "europass-xml", it is empty => hence you receive an empty pdf.

Comment: @LocEngineer I test it and when changing the name from europass-xml to something else I'm redirected to a blank page. I don't know what this means. However I think that's not the problem because the code itself is not using the remote upload service but the REST service, specifically XML to PDF CV [link](http://interop.europass.cedefop.europa.eu/web-services/rest-api-reference/). I Use The Remote Upload just to check if the resulting xml is valid. I'll Upload the Thread. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response body that you receive from the webservice call contains the raw bytes of the PDF.

By running those bytes through a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) you're treating them as if they are text, and then attempting to convert that "text" back to a byte array using [`GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx). I suspect that these steps are corrupting your data.

You should be able to copy the PDF bytes directly to your own [output stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx):

```
// note: this code is completely untested, i don't even know whether it compiles
using (var webResponse = request.GetResponse())
using (var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (webStream != null)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.pdf\"");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        webStream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @LukeH that was a incredible Strike! Thank you very Much! :)

Answer (score 0):

you provide the filepath on server

```
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 return File.OpenRead(downloadFilePath);
```

Comment: Hello @BMaximus, the filepath I'm using is to get the xmlcontent, which is then sent as in the POST request. Can you be more specific?cheers